# Как проверить пустая ли база данных?

Tags: python, sqlite

Ребят подскажите, у меня есть база данных 'data_per.db', в ней есть 3 таблицы users, product, recipe, как можно проверить пустая база данных или нет, имею ввиду созданы ли эти таблицы?
Я использую sqlite
Знаю что вот так возвращается количество в таблице users:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users;"
```

А как именно проверить таблицы в самом файле базы?

Comment: можно создавать таблицу, если она уже есть, то sqlite вернет ошибку IntegrityError

Comment: @ClarkDevlin можно одним SQL запросом создать таблицы если они не существуют. Но вопрос по другому поставлен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так.

```
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect('data_per.db') as con:


    tables = ["'users'","'product'", "'recipe'"]
    table_names = ','.join(tables)

    SQL = f"SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name in ({table_names});"
    num = con.execute(SQL).fetchone()[0]
    if num != len(tables):
        print('Не все таблицы есть')
    else:
        print('Все таблицы есть')
```